# How can I change ViewPager fragment from another fragment? Without doing new

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

This application is a questionnaire.

I used ViewPager to host the fragments.

When the user gets to the last screen, EndingQuestionsFragment, they have a button which then press on and it takes them to the main screen (not important for my problem).

If there is a question which is not answered, when the button is clicked, it should take them to the fragment which contains the question which is not answered.

I used:

```
MainActivity parent = (MainActivity) getActivity();
parent.setPagerFragment(0);
```

Inside a setOnClickListener.

However, when that button is clicked, any answers that were given are reset. (the radioButtons are reset).

How can I navigate through the fragments without losing the inputs?

FragmentCommunicator.java

```
package com.example.zdroa.testinggrounds;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import com.example.zdroa.testinggrounds.Question_Fragments.AnxiousQuestionsFragment;
import com.example.zdroa.testinggrounds.Question_Fragments.DependentQuestionsFragment;
import com.example.zdroa.testinggrounds.Question_Fragments.DepressiveQuestionsFragment;
import com.example.zdroa.testinggrounds.Question_Fragments.EndingQuestionsFragment;
import com.example.zdroa.testinggrounds.Question_Fragments.HistrionicQuestionsFragment;
import com.example.zdroa.testinggrounds.Question_Fragments.InitializerFragment;
import com.example.zdroa.testinggrounds.Question_Fragments.NarcissistQuestionsFragment;
import com.example.zdroa.testinggrounds.Question_Fragments.ObsessiveQuestionsFragment;
import com.example.zdroa.testinggrounds.Question_Fragments.ParanoidQuestionsFragment;
import com.example.zdroa.testinggrounds.Question_Fragments.SchizoidQuestionsFragment;


public class FragmentCommunicator extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    public FragmentCommunicator(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new InitializerFragment();
            case 1:
                return new AnxiousQuestionsFragment();
            case 2:
                return new ParanoidQuestionsFragment();
            case 3:
                return new HistrionicQuestionsFragment();
            case 4:
                return new ObsessiveQuestionsFragment();
            case 5:
                return new NarcissistQuestionsFragment();
            case 6:
                return new SchizoidQuestionsFragment();
            case 7:
                return new DepressiveQuestionsFragment();
            case 8:
                return new DependentQuestionsFragment();
            case 9:
                return new EndingQuestionsFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.zdroa.testinggrounds;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.zdroa.testinggrounds.Question_Fragments.AnxiousQuestionsFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static String PERSON_TYPE;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    public static FragmentCommunicator communicator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpQuestionsActivity);
        communicator = new FragmentCommunicator(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(communicator);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

        int anxious_result = new AnxiousQuestionsFragment().getResult();
        if (anxious_result != 0){
            PERSON_TYPE = "Anxious person";
        }

    }

    public String getPersonType() {
        return PERSON_TYPE;
    }

    public void setPagerFragment(int a){
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(a);
    }    
}
```

EndingQuestionsFragment.java

```
package com.example.zdroa.testinggrounds.Question_Fragments;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.example.zdroa.testinggrounds.MainActivity;
import com.example.zdroa.testinggrounds.R;

public class EndingQuestionsFragment extends Fragment {

    public EndingQuestionsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ending_questions, container, false);

        Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.bGotoMainAreaActivity);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MainActivity parent = (MainActivity) getActivity();
                parent.setPagerFragment(0);
            }
        });



        return view;
    }

}
```

fragment_ending_questions.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fefefe"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context="com.example.zdroa.testinggrounds.Question_Fragments.AnxiousQuestionsFragment">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ending_tv_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="The End"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ending_tv_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ending_tv_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Now that you have answered all the questions please click the Finish button.\n\nIf any questions have been left unanswered you will be taken back to the screen with the missing answeres. Your other answeres will not be affected."
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bGotoMainAreaActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Finish" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpQuestionsActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter`

Comment: you can save the answered question locally in sqlite databas and can update them accordingly

Comment: put in your adapter after case 9    default: break;

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman the questionnaire is only performed once. I think i'm better off just making activities for each set of questions and navigation from one to the other once the answeres are complete, passing the result as putextra to the next activity in the cue?

Comment: @AshishTiwari i'm not exactly sure what you mean. I changed the extends to extend fragmentstatepageradapter. but the same thing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit() in FragmentActivity
Reason why??
Default fragment pager adapter which u used,it destroys and recreates the fragments every time u slide across,using this code u tell it not to destroy the initial fragment state of the previously loaded fragments

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10); // i assumed there are 10 fragments in total
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing:

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return new InitializerFragment();
        case 1:
            return new AnxiousQuestionsFragment();
        case 2:
            return new ParanoidQuestionsFragment();
        case 3:
            return new HistrionicQuestionsFragment();
        case 4:
            return new ObsessiveQuestionsFragment();
        case 5:
            return new NarcissistQuestionsFragment();
        case 6:
            return new SchizoidQuestionsFragment();
        case 7:
            return new DepressiveQuestionsFragment();
        case 8:
            return new DependentQuestionsFragment();
        case 9:
            return new EndingQuestionsFragment();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Create an instance of each fragment at the start (in `onCreate` maybe)

So:

```
InitializerFragment fragmet = new InitializerFragment();
```

Then change your getItem method to do this instead:

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            return fragment;
        case 1:
            // And so on...
}
```

Do this for all the fragments in the viewpager, this way the view pager will preserve the instance of the fragment and keep hold of the answers in the fragment.